# Using regex to split double hyphen but not single hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have an html element id that looks like this:
`dp__1-2--1-3`

I'm trying to use the JavaScript split() function to lop off and return the final '`1-3`'

My regex skills are poor but a bit of searching around got me to this point:

`var myId = "dp__1-2--1-3";
var myIdPostFix = myId.split(/[\-\-]+/).pop();`

Unfortunately that returns me only the '`3`'.

So my question is how do I split double hyphens but NOT single hyphens?

Comment: just `/--/`, no need for []'s

Comment: myId.split("--"); will return an array of results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the brackets in the regular expression that keeps it from working. A set will match one of any of the characers in it, so `[\-\-]` is the same as `[\-]`, i.e. matching a single hyphen.

Just remove the brackets:

```
var myIdPostFix = myId.split(/--/).pop();
```

or just use the string `'--'` instead of a regular expression:

```
var myIdPostFix = myId.split('--').pop();
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa!  That works great (as do the other answers but this one helps me understand better).

Answer (score 1):

[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) accepts a regular expression or a string as the first argument.

You were very close. You can achieve what you want with:

```
var myIdPostFix = myId.split("--").pop();
```